# Wordpress plugin to moderate pages

Tags: content-management-system, wordpress, lamp

I am developing a CMS using wordpress version 3.3.1. By default wordpress has user levels as **contributors** (who write a post but cannot publish or edit a post) and **editors** (who edit a post after it has been published but cannot write a new post).

For my system I would require a user to  have the priviledges to

- Write a new post which remains unpublished until the admin publishes it
- Once it is publised the same user should be able to edit the post
- Once edited the post should be saved as a new version and should remain unpublished till the admin publishes it.
- When published, the old version should be replaced by the newer version.

Basically, my user level is a **hybrid between the contributor and the editor**. I have researched through a lot of plugins that wordpress offers but none would fulfil my need. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the plug-in from [Members Plug-in from Justin Tadlock](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/). It has predefined roles, or you can set up your own levels. The plug-in has a big list of selectable options for configuring custom roles and is simple to use.

Comment: I have used a pluging Role Scoper which along with your plugin can increase the power I want to give to a user. The only unsolved query here remains VERSION CONTROL. The edited post is immediately posted on the live site, I want to restrict this. Any help?